# Chrome auto-filling the username/password in my application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, passwords

I have an application, within which a user creates login details for various sub-users.

When I navigate to any such form for creating a new user, Chrome by default fills the username and password for currently logged-in user in to the form.

I thought Chrome might be picking these fields based on their `id` or `name` (which were earlier `id=username` and `id=password` respectively). However, even after changing these `id` and `name`, Chrome fills the field in the form.

How and Why does Chrome do this. I have been through [this](https://superuser.com/questions/86282/chrome-auto-fill-username-passwords-is-inconsistant)
 and few other links but could not fix this.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm stuck with the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of browser history. try this and it will no longer be problem

1. Open the Chrome menu using the button on the far right of the browser
   toolbar.
2. Choose the Settings menu option.
3. Click the Show advanced
   settings… link located at the bottom of the page. In the “Passwords
   and forms” section, click the Manage passwords link

Comment: I understand this, but the logged-in user would like to save his credentials and the chrome should populate the genuine login form.

Comment: if so the field names of the logged in user should be different from yours so you need to choose different name for your login info entry forms. chrome will not populate values if the name of fields are different from the previously saved. for example assume the logged in user has fields user name and password and you too. in this case his credentials will remain populating. but if you make yours different the problem will be alleviated.

Comment: Are you specifically pointing to the field name (as in the labels that the user will actually see against these input boxes). Because apart from that, I have changed any attribute that might have an impact viz. `id`,`name`, `for`

Comment: Since the field refers to the username and password for the new user to be created, I ma afraid I won't be able to change these fields